# In sentence how to make first letter UPPERCASE followed by dot ('.') and space (zero or more than one )

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
var t = ".i am krishna.   france" // string

  // regular expression to match the pattern where $1 $2 $3 are the grouping
t = t.replace(/[\n]*([a-zA-Z]+[.][ \n]*)([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]*)[\n]*/, '$1' + '$2'.toUpperCase() + '$3');
 $('body').append(t);

//to convert
function convert() {
 return arguments[0].toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

#### Expected result:

```
.I am krishna.  France
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
t = t.replace(/(\. *)([a-z])/g, function($0, $1, $2) { return $1 + $2.toUpperCase(); });
//=> .I am krishna.   France
```

Answer (score 2):

```
([.]\s*)([a-zA-Z])
```

You can use this instead and replace by `'$1'+'$2'.toUpperCase()` to achieve what you want.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/4